# Modify product the moment it's created by WooCommerce Rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have an ERP system creating products in WooCommerce and I need them to be private instead of published.

I tried the hook `woocommerce_rest_insert_product` but it's not doing anything. I've tried adding it on a plugin and on a mu-plugin using `plugins_loaded` action.

I found the hook inside the class `WC_REST_Products_V1_Controller`, in theory it should work...

```
/**
 * Fires after a single item is created or updated via the REST API.
 *
 * @param WP_Post         $post      Post data.
 * @param WP_REST_Request $request   Request object.
 * @param boolean         $creating  True when creating item, false when updating.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_rest_insert_product', $post, $request, false );
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the answer to "why" it's not working.

What I found is [this WordPress.org forum post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-the-term-of-a-custom-taxonomy-to-a-woocommerce-product-using-remote-api/) showing an alternative that works:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_product', function($id, $product ){
    // your thing
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: I have been searching for hours for a good solution, nothing has worked! But the `woocommerce_new_product` did the job very nicely! Thnx for sharing it with us!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late answer but it could make sense for others getting here to read this.

I am pretty sure you are using the latest `v3` of the API.

The problem is that the action you mentioned can be found in `WC_REST_Products_V1_Controller` which has the endpoint namespace set to:

`protected $namespace = 'wc/v1';`

This means it is not usable on the v3.

If you go through the Woocommerce REST controllers in Version 3 you will reach this file:

`includes/rest-api/Controllers/Version3/class-wc-rest-products-controller.php`

which has the namespace set to `wc/v3`;

Here, the class `WC_REST_Products_Controller` extends `WC_REST_Products_V2_Controller`.

In the `WC_REST_Products_V2_Controller` there are the `create_item` and `update_item` methods. Both of these methods look very similar to what was in v1 but, the action name you are looking for is changed to:

```
/**
* Fires after a single object is created or updated via the REST API.
*
* @param WC_Data         $object    Inserted object.
* @param WP_REST_Request $request   Request object.
* @param boolean         $creating  True when creating object, false when updating.
*/
do_action( "woocommerce_rest_insert_{$this->post_type}_object", $object, $request, true );
```

So, your code should look something like:

```
add_action( 
    "woocommerce_rest_insert_product_object", 
    function($product, $request, $creating ){
        // do something here
    }, 10, 3
);
```

The big difference between `woocommerce_new_product` and `woocommerce_rest_insert_{$this->post_type}_object` is that `woocommerce_new_product` is triggered on all create actions, not only on the REST create.

Comment: This seems excellent, will implement asap and report back. Thanks!